# How to Compile a Github Project (Windows)

Tags: github, compilation

I found this project on github https://github.com/noio/kingdom, and i was wondering how I would compile it. Im somewhat new to coding, so if you could answer it simply and clearly that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The project is written in ActionScript (by Adobe) and I recommend you to use [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), a free code editor. Give a look to their [ActionScript 3 wiki](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3), which gives you a full overview of what you need to get started and compile your code. Since you are new to programming I suggest you to start from the very beginning, within a simple `Hello world!` before messing which such big projects (it's a lot of fun, I know :P).